# Trying to connect over spi

Tags: spi

I'm new to programming so don't know much I've been trying to connect the raspberry pi 2 and Arduino uno I've tried over USB with no luck no matter how many times I try to install the Arduino core and IDE when I download everything seems ok but when I try to compile code that I know is right it throws back lots of errors.

So I decided to try spi but not sure what pin is the SS pin I also need the code to make the raspberry pi 2 master

Comment: If you can't communicate from the Arduino IDE via USB you probably haven't set it up for the correct serial port. There are literally thousands of tutorials etc explaining the Pi pins. Try a bit of research, the if you try something and it doesn't work, describe WHAT YOU TRIED and ask a specific question.

Comment: I followed the tutorials and it's still doesn't work and I've also tried to find which pin is the ss I've got a copy of all the pins but it still doesn't tell me what I need to know and as the forum is to help people I thougth people would be willing to help you clearly think that I'm not researching these things first but I'm

Answer (score 2):

On the Raspberry Pi the SS pins are called CE (chip enable) pins. They are named as CE0 and CE1.